# Is there any way to control the logcat output format in intelij 2016?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, log4j

I would like customize the output formt of logcat output to the Logcat panel in the android monitor in intellij.  Is there any way to do this?

Specifically I am using the log4j module that outputs through logcat and there is an indent forced on the message text such that a newline in the message text will indent the subsequent lines. The output is:

```
time date class app blah blah: message line 1(\n)
                               message line 2(\n)
                               mesage line 3
```

I would like to have it be:

```
time date class app blah blah: message line 1(\n)
    message line 2(\n)
    message line 3
```

In my case I have "message line 1" set to the class name and line number in parens, so in intellij window it is clickable

ie: (ClassWithLogLine.java:135)

Answer (score 0):

Well poking at it, it does seem on the Android Monitor logcat tab there is a "gear/sprocket" icon which has checkboxes for turning on and off the various components of the logcat message header, but it still has no control over the message indent nor does it allow you to edit the logcat format string ( ideal for an advanced mode or just showing the field and allow editing of it )